# Left Join in Hibernate query

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Please help me to understand the Hibernate Query written below. I am new to hibernate and finding difficulty to understand some of the queries written in the hibernate query language.

The code is as follows:

```
public List<Product> findByCriteriaByType(Integer orgaId, String categoryName) {
        List<Product> products = null;
        StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            String categoryHql=(categoryName!=null)?" and categoryType.id=:category_type_id":" ";
            hql.append(" from Product product ");
            hql.append(" left join fetch product.category category ");
            hql.append(" left join fetch category.categoryType categoryType ");
            hql.append(" left join fetch product.retailerSnapshots retailerSnapshot ");
            hql.append(" where retailerSnapshot.organization.id=:org_id");
            hql.append(categoryHql);
            products = getProducts("category_type_id",orgaId, categoryName, hql);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
        }
        return products;
    }

private List<Product> getProducts(String parameter,Integer orgaId, String categoryName,StringBuilder hql) {
        Query query;
        query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
        if(categoryName!=null){
            query.setParameter(parameter,Integer.parseInt(categoryName));
        }
        query.setParameter("org_id",orgaId);
        return  query.list();
    }
```

Also let me know the equivalent SQL statement.

Comment: What is not clear for you?

Comment: @meskobalazs : I want to know about the hql statement works in the above case

Answer (score 0):

Your entity schema looks something like this (attributes are omitted):

[image: ER schema]

Your HQL fills the `Product` entity with various fields, coming from various tables. The generated SQL queries of course will depend on the actual tables.

If there is a FK/PK relationship between two tables, most likely it generates a *join*. If there is no relationship between the tables at the DB level, then it generates separate *selects*. By the way, you do not need to guess, as you can get the query plan from Hibernate, and optimize it if you need it.

PS: To help you in finding the equivalent SQL queries, you must provide your actual DB schema. Edit the question with these information, if you can.